# Gradle always downloading when i create a flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

Hello world i'm a beginner in android development with flutter. Why does IntelliJ downloads gradle each time i create a new flutter project even though i have gradle installed on my PC and it's added to path already

Comment: maybe give output of flutter doctor.

Answer (score 0):

The project will use the gradle version which is set in the *build.gradle* file in android/src folder. It's the line that end with **gradle-...-all.zip**. So it will download that version.